# Separador sobrepondo rótulo no novo perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

É mais fácil mostrar do que explicar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha horizontal está cobrindo uma parte do rótulo "Próxima medalha de tag".

Comment: *Em teoria* isso vai ser consertado no próximo build... Mas vou averiguar

Comment: Qual é a diferença de layout e design?

Comment: @Math Eu também gostaria de saber :D Não sei bem como devemos usar essas tags, ou mesmo se elas devem ser sinônimas. Pra mim, design é mais visual, e layout é mais estrutural (como dispor os elementos em blocos).

Comment: @Math eu vejo da mesma forma que o bfavaretto, design faz a minha equipa de design, imagens, cores e textos. layout faço eu, como muito bem disseste dispor elementos em blocos, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tá consertado, vai pro próximo build junto com outras coisas.

Comment: [Estragou de novo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4362/3117)